# Not able to center a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

Yes, there are other questions on this; but I'm not able to make this div center by following their instructions. Why?

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="center"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}

.center {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Does your document have a doctype declaration?

Comment: There is no need for that extra div…

Comment: Matthew - the HTML page does. Poke - not as it stands. I was trying to create a div on the outside that had a background color, and then center my inner div in that outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: fixed` makes the div position itself absolutely (and *fixed*, making it stay where it is when you scroll). This means that auto-margin won’t work. You can either fix this by removing the position rule, or by positioning the div absolutely instead:

```
.center {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

On an unrelated note, the additional `div` is completely useless, you can just leave that out. Also, divs are block elements by default, so you can leave out the `display: block;` rule as well.

Comment: Thanks poke, this is the answer I was looking for. I have it fixed because I don't want it to scroll, but wanted it to be centered on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `position:fixed;` to `position:relative;`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: fixed` from the divs style.

Also, you don't need the display: block... it should default to that anyway. And poke is correct, you shouldn't need that extra div.

Here's an example of it working...
http://jsfiddle.net/VYmw6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` won't get centered because you've got `position:fixed`, if you remove that it will work. :)

See JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6XWMR/

Answer (score 1):

is there any reason why you used `position: fixed`? but the anyway hope this help you

css:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6XWMR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use it !

```
.center {

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 300px;
 }

or

.center {

margin:0 auto; 
width: 300px;
 }
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVVEF/1/) !!

Comment: There is no need to specify "display: block" for a "div" element, they are displayed as block elements by default. At least, according to the recommended default style sheet quoted in CSS 2.1 specification at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to

```
<center>
     <div> 
          content
     </div>
</center>
```

Basically, enclose the div which you want to centered inside the  tag.

Hope this helps and all the best with your project :-)

Comment: Nobody uses "center" tag these days. If you do then I don't even know where to start with my comments...